# Configuring VPN to a specific ip address

Tags: networking, vpn

There is a website that opens only for a specific Ip address.
Which VPN will be helpful in this case?(And how to configure it)?

I use windows and I know the IP address and other settings required to configure to the IP address but I don't know which VPN to use

Comment: It's really not very clear what you're asking. Could you rephrase it a bit. What website are you trying to access?

Comment: Well I am trying to access a website that can be opened only in a local network.I am in the local network.For sometime of the day,the website can only be accessed through a certain set of IP addresses which are functional at a particular location.I want to open the website at this time without going to the area where the website can be accessed

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem by **editing your question** or add additional details by **editing your question** highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, **it’s hard to tell** exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Edited please check

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short version: You can't.

If a server is setup to allow 192.168.1.0/24 (LAN) and then 172.16.0.0/16 (some other LAN, or even internet facing IPs) at another time, no **3rd party** VPN service is going to help.

You would need to use a VPN service whose endpoint is in the latter network. So, you'd need to use a VPN server that is **hosted by that network**. But if that doesn't exist, you can't. And it sounds like it doesn't exist, or you don't have access to it.